# How to align text and icon?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, positioning, text

Here is my code:

```
{\hspace{10mm}\textcolor{brown}{2006 - 2010} \hspace{5mm}} 
{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{BBA Hons (equivalent MBA)} \hspace{6.5mm} 
{\faUniversity}\hspace{2mm}Al Khair University}\hspace{2mm}
\hspace{47mm}  \faMapMarker \hspace{1mm} Pakistan }

{\hspace{10mm}\textcolor{brown}{2005 - 2009} \hspace{5mm}} 
{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{CA Foundation} \hspace{25mm} 
{\faUniversity}\hspace{2mm}Institute of Chartered Accountants}\hspace{26mm}
\faMapMarker \hspace{1mm} Pakistan}


\hspace{10mm} \textcolor{brown}{2011} \hspace{4mm}
{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Certified Internal Auditor (CIA)}}
\hspace{10.4mm} \faUniversity 
\hspace{2mm}\textbf{The Institute of Internal Auditors (IIA)} \hspace{22mm} 
\faMapMarker \hspace{1mm} USA

\hspace{10mm} \textcolor{brown}{2017} \hspace{4mm}
{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{ Certified Public Accountant (CPA)}}
\hspace{5mm} \faUniversity 
\hspace{2mm} \textbf{American Institute of Certified Public Accountants}
\hspace{3mm} \faMapMarker \hspace{1mm} USA
```

[image: As you can see that the text (Years are not Aligned and similarly the University and Location icons are also not aligned)]

Comment: For my humble opinion with many `\hspace` into your code you not will find the correct horizontal-alignment.

Comment: so what I should do instead of \hspace ?

Comment: A `tabular` environment could take care of this.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes can you please give me the full answer with code

Comment: Please provide a complete code that compiles, rather than just a snippet of code.  Should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It basically a resume and I am facing problem in only that part of the code, I can provide all the code to you personally. so tell me how i can share the whole code with you

Comment: I must depart the office presently, but the idea is to strip away all the unnecessary stuff so that the remaining code is the minimal code that demonstrates the issue.  This is what is called an MWE or minimum working example.  We need to see it, so we see what packages are loaded, etc.  You should edit your question to include the MWE.

Comment: Got it, let me edit my code. @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89259/discussion-between-sangeen-khan-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions using `tabulary` and `tabto` respectively:

Without a MWE to work in, this may not fit well in your real document, but it should be easy to adapt to your needs.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{fontawesome,xcolor}  
% for solution A  only:
\usepackage{tabulary,array} 
% for solution B only:
\usepackage{tabto}  
\TabPositions{.12\linewidth,.46\linewidth,.75\linewidth,.89\linewidth}
\newcommand\myrow[4]{\noindent\textcolor{brown}{#1}\tab%
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}\tab%
\faUniversity\quad\parbox[t]{.35\linewidth}{\raggedright #3}\tab%
 \faMapMarker~#4\par}

\begin{document}\sffamily

\section*{Solution A}
\extrarowheight1ex
\noindent\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}
>{\color{brown}}l
>{\bfseries\color{blue}}l
>{\faUniversity~}lL
>{\faMapMarker~}ll@{}}
2006 -- 2010 & BBA Hons (equivalent MBA) && Al Khair University && Pakistan\\
2005 -- 2009 & CA Foundation && Institute of Chartered Accountants && Pakistan\\
2011 & Certified Internal Auditor (CIA) && The Institute of Internal Auditors (IIA) && USA\\
2017 & Certified Public Accountant (CPA) && American Institute of Certified Public Accountants && USA\\
\end{tabulary}
\section*{Solution B}
{\parskip1ex
\myrow{2006 - 2010}{BBA Hons (equivalent MBA)}{Al Khair University}{Pakistan}
\myrow{2005 - 2009}{CA Foundation}{Institute of Chartered Accountants}{Pakistan}
\myrow{2011}{Certified Internal Auditor (CIA)}{The Institute of Internal Auditors (IIA)}{USA}
\myrow{2017}{Certified Public Accountant (CPA)}{American Institute of Certified Public Accountants}{USA}}
\end{document}
```